# C# - Connecting to an Access MDB file using WPF (The ConnectionString Property has not been initialized)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ms-access, oledbconnection

Let me start by saying I've only been coding C# for about 3-4 month.

I am trying to get a basic understanding of how databases are accessed within Visual studio so that I can both insert, update and delete data. I have tried various different tests and I think I've come to the conclusion that there's something about WPF's that OleDb doesn't quite like. I have created 2 identical projects, one using Windows Forms and another using WPF. The Windows Forms version of the project works absolutely fine however the WPF project does not, giving me the error

"The ConnectionString Property has not been initialized"

I have no idea how to fix this. I've been scouring the internet for the best part of 12 hours and still had absolutely no success.

Here is the original code for the WPF file. It is the same as the Windows Form code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataReader dr;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\MarkB\Documents\testing.mdb";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        loaddata();
    }
    private void loaddata()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        listBox4.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            string q = "select * from info";
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.HasRows)
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    listBox3.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                    listBox4.Items.Add(dr[3].ToString());
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox l = sender as ListBox;
        if(l.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
            listBox3.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
            listBox4.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((textBox1.Text!="") && (textBox2.Text!=""))
        {
            string q ="insert into info (firstname,surname,address) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text +"')";
            dosomething(q);
            textBox1.Text = null;
            textBox2.Text = null;
            textBox3.Text = null;
        }
    }

    private void dosomething(String q)
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            cn.Close();
            loaddata();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox1.SelectedIndex !=-1)
            {
            string q = "delete from info where id =" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dosomething(q);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. I know the problem must stem from the connection aspect of the code

Comment: UI frameworks have nearly no relationship with database frameworks. So why mix them up into your question?

Comment: @LeiYang Because for some reason the choice of UI is disrupting the code that allows me to connect to my database. test it out for yourself, create a simple WPF and Windows form application and test out this code. One will work (The windows form) and the other wont (the WPF). 

I much prefer using WPF when designing my programs so I would really like to get to the bottom of this problem.

Comment: I really don't know why you are mixing, besides, if you are using WPF, why not use **bindings & MVVM**?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception? Have you verified that the WPF application is actually executing your `Form1_Load` method?

Comment: @GordThompson it is occurring at cn.ConnectionString

Comment: What window event is the `Form1_Load` method associated with? FWIW, I am unable to reproduce your issue when I use `<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" ... Loaded="Form1_Load">`.

Comment: it's handles all of the connection properties. All of this code is handled within the MainWindow.xaml.cs file. You could rename it to Connections if you'd like. It wouldn't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that the connection is being called at some point BEFORE the connection string has been passed to it. Maybe try setting the connection string right at the top when you first instantiate the OleDbConnection object:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\MarkB\\Documents\\testing.mdb");
```

Then create a new cmd object everytime you need it (rather than once at the top):

```
string query = "select * from somethingorother";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
```